# Issue with Jackson DefaultScalaModule (couldn't deserialize a bean from JSON)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON to case class. Here is my model

```
case class Animal(
  @JsonProperty("name")         name      : String,
  @JsonProperty("weight")       weight    : Double,
  @JsonProperty("unit-of-mass") unitOfMass: String
)
```

My JSON file

```
[
  {
    "name"         : "Elephant",
    "weight"       : "13227.74",
    "unit-of-mass" : "lbs"
  },
  {
    "name"         : "Panther",
    "weight"       : "31",
    "unit-of-mass" : "kg"
  }
]
```

And mapping

```
val animals = sc.textFile("file:///...")
val mapper = new ObjectMapper

mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val json = animals.collect.mkString

val seq =
  mapper.readValue(json, classOf[List[Animal]]) map {
    case a @ Animal(n, w, u) => a
  }

seq.foreach(println)
```

Here is the error I've got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3 cannot be cast test.Animal
```

Seems Jackson couldn't deserialize JSON to bean, and instead of that is makes a map of maps. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to use `classOf[Array[Animal]]` type value.

Comment: Instead of `mapper.readValue(...)` try `parse(json).extract[List[Animal]]`